# How to disable edit boxes from a TInputQueryWizardPage input page?

Tags: inno-setup

Is it possible to conditionally disable or hide edit boxes from a [TInputQueryWizardPage](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_scriptclasses.htm#TInputQueryWizardPage) input page (page created by using [CreateInputQueryPage](http://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/topic_isxfunc_createinputquerypage.htm) function) ?

I have 4 edit boxes and I need to disable/hide the last two of them, based on the input from the previous wizard page. How can I do it ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can access them through the [`TInputQueryWizardPage.Edits`](http://www.jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=scriptclasses&anchor=TInputQueryWizardPage) indexed property:

```
[Code]
var
  FirstEditIndex: Integer;
  SecondEditIndex: Integer;
  InputPage: TInputQueryWizardPage;  

procedure InitializeWizard;
begin
  InputPage := CreateInputQueryPage(wpWelcome, 'Caption', 'Dscription', 'SubCaption');

  // the Add method returns the Index of the just added edit box, and
  // you need to store those indexes to access the edit boxes later on
  FirstEditIndex := InputPage.Add('Name:', False);
  SecondEditIndex := InputPage.Add('Surname:', False);

  // access the edits through the stored indexes; in your case this will 
  // happen in the other event, so take this script as a showcase
  InputPage.Edits[FirstEditIndex].Enabled := False;  
  InputPage.Edits[SecondEditIndex].Visible := False;  
end;
```